# Assumption of Type in Custom Type with Strongly-Typed Properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Consider the following Typescript types...

```js
export type Dog = {
    color: string,
    earsFloppy: boolean,
    _type: "dog"
}

export type Fish = {
    color: string,
    finsFlowy: boolean,
    _type: "fish"
}

export type Pet = Dog | Fish;

export type PetMap = {
    dog: Dog[],
    fish: Fish[]
}
```

Consider the following function (also in Typescript)...

```js
var myPetMap = { dog: [], fish: [] };

function addToPetMap(newPet: Pet): void {
    myPetMap[newPet._type].push(newPet);    
}
```

I have a nearly identical setup in my project, but I get the following error:

> `[ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((...items: Dog[]) => number) | ((...items: Fish[]) => number)' has no compatible call signatures. [2349]`

But doing the following resolves the issue...

```js
var myPetMap = { dog: [], fish: [] };

function addToPetMap(newPet: Pet): void {
    switch(newPet._type) {
        case 'dog':
            myPetMap[newPet._type].push(newPet);
        break;
        case 'fish':
            myPetMap[newPet._type].push(newPet);
        break;
    }
}
```

It's as if the value of `newPet._type` must be known or concrete in the scope that `myPetMap[newPet._type].push(newPet)` exists. It cannot exist in a scope where the value of `newPet._type` is not guaranteed to be `dog` (x)or `fish`.

However, because the *type* of `Dog._type` is `"dog"` and the *type* of `Fish._type` is `"fish"`, the value of `Dog._type` can *only* be `"dog"` and the value of `Fish._type` can *only* be `"fish"`. I don't exactly see why

```js
myPetMap[newPet._type].push(newPet);
```

is erroneous.

When the `Pet` that's passed in is a `Dog`, `newPet._type` can only be `"dog"` and the new pet will be added to `myPetMap["dog"]`, which is an array of `Dog` objects.

When the `Pet` that's passed in is a `Fish`, `newPet._type` can only be `"fish"` and the new pet will be added to `myPetMap["fish"]`, which is an array of `Fish` objects.

Because the type of the `_type` property for both types that `Pet` may be is a fixed value, I don't see how there could ever be any type mismatch issues where a `Dog` is added to the `Fish` array or vice-versa. The value of `newPet._type` shouldn't need to be made concrete or known in order to add it to the correct array.

Is there any way around this? Any Typescript compiler options or different ways of writing this?

EDIT:

> The type of `newPet._type` is `string`.

This is what I thought at one point, but attempting to change the value of `newPet._type` yields its own error...

```js
newPet._type = "Something Else";
```

```
[ts] Type '"Something Else"' is not assignable to type '"dog" | "fish"'. [2322]
(property) _type: "dog" | "fish"
```

Comment: The type of `newPet._type` is *string*.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for the quick response. I've edited my post to address your comment.

Comment: But obviously if your `switch` statement works, the type of `_type` is string; `switch` statement comparisons are made with `===` logic.

Comment: @Pointy at runtime `_type` is a string, but typescript has string ilteral types to model string constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There nothing wrong with your approach, but you did hit a limitation of the type system. Typescript can't follow relationship between variables so typescript can't tell the difference between your function and this one:

```
function addToPetMap(_type: "dog" | "fish", newPet: Pet): void {
    myPetMap[_type].push(newPet);    
}
```

In the example above one could pass in `'dog'` and an instance of `Fish`. While in your case this is can't happen because `_type` comes from `newPet` the compiler can't follow this, it just sees the type of `newPet._type` as `"dog" | "fish"` and raises an error.

Your workaround of using a switch is the very safe way of doing this. A type assertion is also appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Titian. Is there a solution as safe as the switch statement but without the plaintext redundancy of it? If I wanted to support 100 different types of `Pet` the switch statement would be very large.

Comment: @Zulfe not as far as I know. jcalz has an issue on github with a similar scenario to this which is still open so I doubt there is a better solution.